# How do I create a bookmarklet that updates an AngularJS input element and updates the scope?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bookmarklet

When I run this bookmarklet JavaScript, the model doesn't update on the angular scope. How do I trigger a scope update or digest cycle so that the view model is aware of the updated input element value?

```
//This doesn't work, but it does update the input box:

javascript:(function(){
    var elementText = 'Changed text';
    var inputElement = document.getElementById('inputBox');
    inputElement.value = elementText;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that triggering the elements change event triggers an Angular digest cycle:

```
javascript:(function(){
    var elementText = 'Changed text';
    var inputElement = document.getElementById('inputBox');
    inputElement.value = elementText;
    if ("createEvent" in document) { 
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
        inputElement.dispatchEvent(evt); 
    } else {
        inputElement.fireEvent("onchange");
    }
})();
```